# How to reset master detail page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

Im trying to built an app using xamarin forms.
I have a navigation drawer implemented using MasterDetail page. I need to reset the content of MasterDetail when user press backbutton and revist the same screen again. While trying to do this Im getting following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Master must not already have a parent.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "reset the content"? And when it should do this? And you mean hardware back button? Please provide more details.

Comment: I need to reinitialise the pages in master details page. And i need to do this, when user press hardware back button and revisit the page again

Comment: As I know, Xamarin.Forms don't provide a hook to know when a user pressed hardware back. But I think it is not what you need. When you revisit the page, it initializes every time, so I don't see a problem. But if you wanna do some changes, you can use one of the MVVM frameworks(I use Prism) and do some code in the method, that is called when you navigates to your page.
About your exception, I don't know what it means. Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this same issue as well trying to set a new MasterdetailPage() as the Application.Current.MainPage. The previous page intances inside the MasterdetailPage.Detail remain somewhere in memory, This can cause events to fire twice due to MessagingCenter not being able to unsubscribe.

Solution was to save an instance of the MasterDetailPage inside a Global variable and reuse this instance for the Application.Current.MainPage. This way no new pages are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear parent of the new page before set the masterdetailpage instance.

```
newPage.Parent = null;
 MyMasterDetailPage.Instance.Detail = newPage;
```